# Is FluorineFX mature enough to use for a large web application?

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, web-applications, amf, fluorinefx

I am in the planning stages of developing a large web application written in Flex and was wondering if anyone has actually used FluorineFX in a large production environment?

The documentation and online community makes it seem like it could be abandoned in the years to come and I have yet to read about it being used in production.

I have been assessing Weborb as well, but the costs are extremely high and I'm not entirely satisfied with the general workflow/setup of it. Are there any other solutions out there that I should consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used FlourineFx with great success in a large product with a Flex 3 client, and it actually works better than the ColdFusion (Adobe LiveCycle) product it replaced. It does require some configuration to work correctly, but it seems to work quite well once your config files are set up -- then again, its the same config files that Adobe LiveCycle need.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Justin. Did you have any major issues with development speed, security, or performance?

Comment: Not really, especially if you are setting the .NET types on the Flex side as well. It's performance has been better than the ColdFusion-based system it replaced. I can't compare it with other solutions other than ColdFusion however.

Comment: I've also used FluorineFX with great success in a large product and it worked great. I like it more than WebORB because you have access to the source code. But I have also seen a project using .NET MVC JSON and Flex and this is also a good approach. On my johlero blog you'll find a lot of usefull information about FluorineFX, .NET MVC, WCF, ...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about FlourineFX. It looks like it is either just getting started or ending.

Working with DotNet and Flex, I would recommend writing the Flex Client and using ASP.NET web services to communicate. Microsoft ASP.NET MVC is a wonderful framework that is free and well supported. See: http://www.asp.net/mvc

The advantage of using a web service is that the client can change so that if you decide against Flex in the future or decide to use a Mobile Client then the service will remain the same. Plus, ASP.NET MVC has been proven on some very large sites like SO here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The reason I haven't considered web services is the performance issues. Performance will be critical for this application and from what I have read, there is a lot of overhead with web services which makes them considerably slower than AMF. I have experienced this firsthand with a project written in ColdFusion. Switching from Web Services to AMF was like day and night, but could ASP.NET's web services be faster than ColdFusion's?